# Unable to add ListItem Dynamically into the list in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have been trying to add ListItem dynamically, what is wrong in the below code snippet?

```
  function nativePluginResultHandler (result)
        {
           alert ("My Result" + result);           
            var listWid = dijit.byId("mylist");
            alert (" hook 1");
            var cw = new dojox.mobile.ListItem ({id: "Jitem1", label:"blabla"});
            alert ( "hook 2");
            listWid.addChild(cw);
            alert ( "Hook 3");

}
```

The "My Result " alert message is displayed, and after that nothing happens?.. Kindly let know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i found the answer:. :)

```
    require (["dijit/registry", "dojo/domReady!"], function (registry) {
             var list = registry.byId("mylist");
             var childWidget = new dojox.mobile.ListItem ({id: "item1" , label:"newRecord"} );
             list.addChild (childWidget);

             });
```

The above code worked.